# Docker: npm run start causing error, EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/node/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache

Tags: reactjs, docker, permissions, dockerfile, npm-start

I have created a react app and trying to run it over the docker container with volumes (mapping content inside the container with outside files), everything was working fine earlier but now facing an issue as shared.
Can anyone help me with that? This is a permission issue but doesn't know how to resolve that. root user has access of  node_modules folder. How to give access to node user ?

My docker file

```
FROM node:alpine

USER node
WORKDIR '/home/node'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Commands used:

```
docker build -t frontend -f Dockerfile.dev .
```

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /home/node/node_modules -v $(pwd):/home/node frontend:latest
```

[image: project structure]

Error:
[image]

Access in container:

```
~ $ ls -l
total 1488
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           124 Jun 20 08:37 Dockerfile.dev
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node          3369 Jun 17 18:25 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    3 node     node          4096 Jun 17 18:45 build
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           230 Jun 20 06:56 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwxr-x 1041 root     root         36864 Jun 20 19:15 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node       1457680 Jun 18 18:28 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 node     node           811 Jun 17 18:26 package.json
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Jun 17 18:25 public
drwxrwxr-x    2 node     node          4096 Jun 17 18:25 src
```

Comment: try running `chmod 777 /app/node_modules`, and also please do not post pictures in your questions, copy the text over here

Comment: This command is not working, showing operation not permitted.
I have added few more details to question if it helps to resolve.

Comment: did you try it with `sudo`? like `sudo chmod 777 /app/node/node_moduels`

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the host's `node_modules` directory from the image?  The `docker run -v` options replace the image content with things from other places, which makes this setup not especially reproducible; does deleting these options help?

Comment: None of the above-mentioned approaches worked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is clear that node_modules folder in container is built by root user during the step npm install, therefore has root as user.
This is the reason we don't have access to that folder when we set up our node user.
To resolve this what we have to do is firstly using the root user we have to give permission to the node user while copying files from local directory to image and then later set up node as the user as shown below:

```
COPY --chown=node:node package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .
USER node
```

Comment: This is the only solution that actually worked for me in wsl2 ubuntu /w docker.

Comment: This explains the problem exactly. I deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and did a fresh `npm i` with the correct user

Answer (score 1):

This file is not a very important file that can cause major application failures if removed. its just a cache file created by external dependencies using eslinter. You can just safely remove by running

```
sudo rm /home/$USER/path-to-your-project/node_modules/.cache/.eslintcache
```

Comment: In my case the server wouldn't start if the EACCESS error occured during build... I had to fix the permissions. It seems ignoring it is not always an option!

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.eslintignore` file and put `*` in it.

Answer (score 0):

if you'r running docker-compose, changing the Dockerfile when npm installing worked for me after a lot of investigation

```
RUN cd /usr/src/app && npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but nether of proposed solutions here worked for me so I searched for a "Docker volume permision denied on linux" an I found this post: [Docker permission denied with volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51864245/7078332) where explains you need enable the `permissive` option on SELinux

Answer (score -1):

Just insert below line in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod 777 /app/node_modules
```

before line:

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Rebuild it. Do not need to touch anything else.

Comment: Granting 777 is more a work-around. Definitely works. Cause is that the file owner and user in context are different. Appreciate your participation.

Comment: Please beware! `chmod 777` will make all folders and files in that directory accessible to any user on your system (even a service account).

Answer (score -1):

This error was haunting me while I was developing a react web app , So here the `eslint` is asking for few permission that I was not able to find  what kind of permission is required so i decided to give all permission available , and that worked for me .

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /yourProjectDirectoryName
```

Here the project directory is your directory from home to your current folder.

If this didn't work try going through this, https://idqna.madreview.net/

Comment: Please beware! `chmod -R 777` will make all folders and files recursively in that directory accessible to any user on your system (even a service account).

Comment: so do u have any alternative to this , please do suggest me !

Comment: 777 is read, write, and execute for the owner, the group, and all others. Obviously, the issue is that the process trying to access the eslint cache does not have permission, so the solution is to figure out what effective user ID the process is running as. If it's the wrong user, fix that. If it's the right user, check the file ownership and permissions, and adjust them if they're wrong. Your answer is not so much an adjustment of permissions as it is disabling permission-based access control.

Answer (score -1):

I have easily solved the issue using "sudo" in the command:

```
sudo npm start
```

Comment: This is not safe to ever do! Packages on npm and their dependencies can be malicious, and running packages with sudo will give them administrator privileges. Even benign npm packages can have vulnerabilities, and running vulnerable packages with sudo will allow any RCE vulnerability to give an attacker administrator privileges instead of user privileges. If a package needs administrator privileges, it will let you know.